# Where does the Vitali set exist?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In an exercise it was asked to show that there exists a non-measurable set (Vitali set) in $[0, 1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. I was able to prove this using the standard approach using translation invariance.

My question is there a condition such that, given some subset $E \subset \Bbb R$, there exists a non-measurable set in $E$?

Or does the Vitali set only exist in $[0,1)?$ Does Vitali set exist in more than one dimension?

Comment: No, the Vitali set exists  in every set of positive measure. You can do a Vitali like construction in such sets using a  similar approach. In short, the equivalence classes that you get during the construction have to be intersected with the set you want to create your Vitali set in.

Comment: I usually see the Vitali set defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it does exist in greater dimensions. I think the only difference between the 1-dimensional and the n-dimensional cases is in how you define your equivalence classes: $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are rationally equivalent if $x_i - y_i = q_i$ for all $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$, where $q_i \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Can we say it is unique in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @Riaz I don't see what exactly you mean, but remember that if you translate a set by any number, it doesn't change it's measurability. Therefore, for example, if $V$ is a Vitali set, so is $\{v+1 : v \in V\}$. Uniqueness is then unrealistic to expect. You can also scale : for example, $\{\frac v2 : v \in \mathbb V\}$ will also be a Vitali set. This way, you can create many such sets and cause further problems. So uniqueness is not true.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Riaz You're welcome. Most likely, non-measurability (at least with respect to the Lebesgue measure) is something you only need to know as an "it's there, but it can be easily dealt with" concept. However, non-measurability with respect to general sigma-algebras in probability is a lot more significant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the Axiom of Choice. It can be shown that if $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has positive Lebesgue measure, then $S$ contains a non-measurable subset.

The construction of Vitali set can be modified for any $S$.

Vitali sets also exist in higher dimensions. If $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is a Vitali set on $\mathbb{R}$, then $V \times U$ for any $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is non-measurable. (Unless $\lambda(U) = 0$)

Comment: So they lurks around us at all times but we can't see them, lovely.

Comment: @Lookbehindyou But only if you believe in the axiom of choice. :-)

Comment: Here is a fun one.  Almost all real numbers cannot be uniquely mathematically specified.  Proof, the set of possible mathematic statements (including specifications) is countable, therefore the set of numbers that are specifiable is countable.  There are an uncountable number  of reals.  Question, what does it mean to say that numbers exist that cannot ever be specified?

Comment: We can show there exists $ S\subset R$ such that whenever $C$ is an uncountable closed subset of $R$, then $C\cap S\ne \phi \ne C\cap (R- S). $ So any closed subset of $S$  or of $R-S$, is countable, and hence Lebesgue-null.  When $E$ is measurable and not Lebesgue-null, the inner measure of $E\cap S$ and of $E\cap (R-S)$ are each $0$, so $ E\cap S$ is not measurable.